# jQuery - toggle ul in li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of editing the menu.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}

li.menu-toggle {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 1%, green 100%);
    background-color: red;
}

.menu-toggle ul {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-toggle ul li{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-toggle">Toggle
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How to toggle `ul` under first li? Now the menu expands inside the first (clickable) `li`. I want the clickable element to always be above the expanded values (typical menu).

I tried different toggle combinations but unfortunately the result is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the submenu events from bubbling up to the parent element.
https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
$('.sub-menu').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: It's working for me - https://jsfiddle.net/humanman555/z6k4ptfx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(this)` use `$(e.target).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');`

Try this one:

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

```css
    a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

        li {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5em;
        }

            li.menu-toggle {
                background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 1%, green 100%);
                background-color: red;
            }

        .menu-toggle ul {
            position: relative;
        }

            .menu-toggle ul li {
                background-color: blue;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="menu-toggle">
    Toggle
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Update based on OP's comment**

You want parent element (blue `li`) has put at top of `ul` tag. So put the `ul` tag next to the `li` (It is better to use div instead of`li` here).

And for your jQuery part use `$(e.target).next().slideToggle('slow');`

```js
 $('.menu-toggle').click(function (e) {
            $(e.target).next().slideToggle('slow');
 })
```

```css
  a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

        li {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5em;
        }

            li.menu-toggle {
                background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 1%, green 100%);
                background-color: red;
            }

            ul li {
                background-color: blue;
            }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <li class="menu-toggle">
        Toggle
    </li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @olqa101 that has happened because you are using `ul,li` and always `li` ha put in corresponding  `ul`

Comment: @olqa101 I updated my answer. Now the blue part has put below of red part

Comment: Thank you, but I can't change HTML. It has to be this structure, unfortunately.

Comment: I spend two hours for you! you put the tag inside other tag but you want to show out of it. The only way is change the structure. with html Or jQuery. if you don't have access to html use jquery to change the structure of element

Comment: Small question. Do you think it is appropriate to change the html tag by jQuery? (replaceWith function e.g li -> span). I find conflicting opinions on this. And thank you for your time and help.

Comment: In your case not. but generally you can create tag and append to another by jQuery